# increamental loop in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

i want to print the

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
```

pattern on console in 8086 emulator, but i did not know how to make an incremental loop in assembly please help me??
i am trying following code but it does not work

```
; You may customize this and other start-up templates; 
; The location of this template is c:\emu8086\inc\0_com_template.txt

org 100h

.data 

size dw 5
iner dw 1

.code

mov cx,size
dec cx

outer:

mov dx,cx

mov ah,2
mov dl,' '
int 21h

mov cx,5

inner:

mov ah,2
mov dl,'*'
int 21h



loop inner

mov ah,2



mov cx,dx 
loop outer

ret
```

Comment: `dl` is the low byte of `dx`, so you are overwriting your counter. There may be other problems too. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Try the `loop` instruction. http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#LOOP

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the code below seems tou're missing construction like:

```
label:
//do something
    dec register
    jnz label
```

So your task should look something like this:

```
    place=1
    line_length=5

    space_count=line_length
print_spaces:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,' '
    int 21h
    dec space_count
    jnz print_spaces

    dots_count=place
print_dots:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,'*'
    int 21h
    dec dots_count
    jnz print_dots

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,'\n'
    int 21h
    inc place
    dec line_length
    jnz print_spaces

    ret
```